# If no two elements of an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ are coprime, then the set has a common divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider an infinite subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that no two distinct elements are coprime.

Does it follow that there is a positive integer $g>1$ such that $g$ divides every element in $S$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=\{15k:k\in\mathbf N\}\cup\{21\}\cup\{35\}$. Then each pair is not relatively prime, but $\gcd(15,21,35)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

This fails even if $S$ has only $3$ elements: no two of $6,10,15$ are coprime, but the greatest common divisor is $1$.